# Showing Fake records in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 application which has a data entry div(HTML div) and a data view div.

The data entered from data entry div is posted to MVC controller which will then store to database.
The data view div will get updated every 2 seconds via an jquery Ajax call.

The problem here is , the database call from MVC controller to store the data will approximately take 10 secs. And hence the user will not be seeing any data in the data view div for 10 secs.

My requirement is that , I need to show a dummy record in data view div with status as "In progress" until the actual data gets stored and retrieved from database.Once the data is retrieved form data base , I need to replace this dummy record with original record with status as "Completed".

I thought of using field variables of MVC controller. But since HTTP is stateless, I do not want to use this approach. Is there any pattern or way to do this?

Comment: Why on earth does it take 10 seconds to add a some data to database?  I would suggest your time is better spent figuring out why that is so slow.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: It is done via Azure service bus messagin queues and hence it takes long time.

Comment: Using a messaging queue does not automatically take a long time... but if your backend servicing process is backed up and takes 10 seconds to get to it, then I see.  In which case, you are dealing with a standard page refresh scenario.. you have to keep checking the result on a page refresh until the result is done.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: Yes I am continuously refreshing. But at the same time I need to inform the user that the work is in progress.To do that , I need to cache the data from the data entry div.

Comment: You could Make the POST call an async controller and return the the data that you passed it in the model (it will come back almost immediately). Then just write to the database async and you'll get the result after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **Session** variable in MVC to store the data entered by the user and showed the same details to the user as "In Progress" until the actual database call returns me the data.